# i want to let the user input a number 3 times at most

Tags: python

```
import random
attempt =0
while attempt <=3:
rand = random.randint(1,18)
age = int(input(“please input your age:”))
if(int(age) == rand):
        print(“great”)
    elif age< rand:
        print (“smaller than the true value”)
    elif age > rand):
        print (“larger than the true value”)
```

Generate a random age (1~18), let the user input the age for at most 3 times, if the input is the same as the random number, output 'Great', if it is smaller, output 'Smaller than the true value', if it is larger, output 'Larger than the true value'

my code works but it keep repeating even if it is already more than 3

Comment: Define a counter variable that is incremented in each iteration and use it in a while loop or a break statement.

Comment: You set `attempt` to 0 before starting the loop. But then it never changes, so it will be **always lesser than 3**.

Comment: @studying your code as shown has indentation errors which are significant for Python. You should fix thos before attempting to solve further problems.

Comment: 1. Set rand before the while loop.  2.  break if `age == rand`, 3. Increment attempts otherwise.  4. Fix indentation

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you increase the value of attempt everytime you get an answer. Also, fix some indentation error:

```
import random
attempt = 0
while attempt < 3:
    rand = random.randint(1,18)
    age = int(input("Please enter your age"))
    if(int(age) == rand):
        print("Great")
    elif age< rand:
        print ("smaller than the true value")
    elif age > rand:
        print ("larger than the true value")
    attempt += 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the user was to be given three attempts to guess one random age rather than trying to guess different random ages 3 times.  Otherwise, knowing if the guess was smaller or larger wouldn't matter.

Comment: @DarrylG I think you are correct. If that is the case, the asker can put rand line outside of the while loop and it will work!